# CAShapeLayer for draw triangle with rectangle

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cashapelayer

I want to draw triangle with rectangle like this image.

[image]

But I can draw like this shape using this code.
[image]

```
CAShapeLayer *mask = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
mask.frame = imgTest.layer.bounds;
CGFloat width = imgTest.layer.frame.size.width;
CGFloat height = imgTest.layer.frame.size.height;
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 30, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, width, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, width, height);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, height);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 30, 0);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path); mask.path = path;
CGPathRelease(path);
imgTest.layer.mask = mask;
```

So how can I draw like first image shape?

Comment: Turn your computer upside down. But seriously - I think if you just try to understand the code you have, you should be able to change it easily.

Comment: @rghome Yes. I did some research about CAShapeLayer but I couldn't understand as how to set CGPathMoveToPoint and CGPathAddLineToPoint. After see the bellow answer I can able to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CAShapeLayer *mask = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
mask.frame = imgTest.layer.bounds;
CGFloat width = imgTest.layer.frame.size.width;
CGFloat height = imgTest.layer.frame.size.height;
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, width, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, width-30, height);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, height);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path); mask.path = path;
CGPathRelease(path);
imgTest.layer.mask = mask;
```

Comment: Ya. That is the answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Hemal. Welcome. Mask answer please :)